Unable to Insert Managed Package Object Records in Test Context Despite Success in Anonymous Window
I am facing an issue while writing a test class for a business process that involves managed package objects. The object in question has a trigger within the managed package.
When I execute the same code in the Anonymous Window, it successfully inserts records. However, when I run the test class, it throws the following error:
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: namespace.ObjTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

I suspect this might be related to the managed package's trigger context behaving differently during test execution, but I am unsure how to resolve this. Here are the steps I have tried:

Ensured that all required fields for the object are populated in the test class.
Used Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() blocks to isolate test execution.
Checked that there are no validation rules or dependencies that might cause issues during the test execution.

Despite these efforts, the error persists.
Questions:

Why does the same code work in the Anonymous Window but fail in the test class?
Are there specific considerations or limitations when dealing with managed package triggers in test contexts?
How can I debug or bypass this issue to successfully test my functionality?

Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

I take it you don't own the managed package? If that's the case, you should take this up with the vendor as I suspect you are right and they have some hacky "is test running" check in their trigger/handler. The error you report makes it look like some record (the one you are creating, or some related record perhaps) gets explicitly added to a DML from within the trigger itself (when it is already being processed in a DML).
